# Advanced MySQL query, group 1 column

Tags: php, mysql

if this is possible

i have in base like this:

```
AAA 1
AAA 2
BBB 1
BBB 2
BBB 3
```

and result must be like this

```
AAA 1   2   
BBB 1   2   3
```

or

```
AAA 1,2 
BBB 1,2,3
```

tnx

Comment: use [group_concat](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php)

Comment: Use group_concat(column2,',') with group by column1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT`.

**Query**

```
select column1,
group_concat(column2 separator ',') as column2
from tableName
group by column1;
```

**Result**

```
+---------+---------+
| column1 | column2 |
+---------|---------+
| AAA     | 1,2     |
| BBB     | 1,2,3   |
+---------+---------+
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9969d/1)

If you want to separate with space`( )` instead of comma`(,)`,
then specify `separator ' '` in the `group_concat`.

Then the query would be something like below:

```
select column1,
group_concat(column2 separator ' ') as column2
from tableName
group by column1;
```

**Result**

```
+---------+---------+
| column1 | column2 |
+---------|---------+
| AAA     | 1 2     |
| BBB     | 1 2 3   |
+---------+---------+
```

[**Read more about `group_concat` here**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

## `UPDATE`

If you need the each `column2` value in separate columns,
then you may need to execute a dynamic sql query.

**Query**

```
set @query = null;
select
group_concat(distinct
    concat(
      'max(case when column2 = ''',
      column2, ''' then column2 end) as Value_',column2
    )
  ) into @query
from tableName ;

set @query = concat('select column1, ', @query, ' from tableName 
                  group by column1
');

prepare stmt from @query;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

**Result**

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| column1 | Value_1 | Value_2 | Value_3 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| AAA     |  1      |  2      | (null)  |
| BBB     |  1      |  2      | 3       |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9969d/4)

Comment: Then, each value in different columns??